# rhel + adding swap memory without reboot

Tags: linux, rhel, memory, swap

we do the following procedure in order to add swap memory on `rhel 7.x` machine

so before the swap additional memory we have :

```
free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             38          31           1           0           5           5
Swap:             3           0           3
```

and the add swap procedure is like this

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile-additional bs=1M count=10000
mkswap /swapfile-additional
echo "/swapfile-additional swap swap    0   0" >>/etc/fstab
mount -a
swapon -a
swapon -s
```

now we can see the new values after adding swap memory

```
 free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             38          31           0           0           6           6
Swap:            13           0          13
```

we can see that swap increase by `10G`

regarding to above procedure we have three questions

1. how to disable the additional of `10G` that we performed  ? ( to get the stat before the swap increasing )
2. since doing `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile-additional bs=1M count=10000` , take time , I want to ask if something else can replace it or other cli
3. since swap memory is much slow then dimm memory then what is the maz swap that we can use from total memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `mount -a`

This command is redundant. Swap is not "mounted" it's either used or not used.

1. `swapoff /swapfile-additional`
2. It's currently the only valid way. Preallocated files may not always work.
3. > then what is the maz swap that we can use from total memory ?

It's hard to understand what you really mean.

Comment: about step 3 I mean - what we cant do with swap for example if we have 32G memory , and we add 32G swap - is it valid also ? or we need to set limit for swap

Comment: second - how much swap is slow from memory when using ssd disks ?

Comment: It depends on the apps you're running. You may as well have no swap at all. If you're running out of swap hard, you may want to have more RAM or distribute your tasks among different servers. I prefer not to have SWAP ever because it rarely helps but may cause huge slow downs.

Comment: It sounds like yael is using swap to extend usable memory and not as an emergency fallback for unusual circumstances.